# Dynamic Deployment of pods as per some conditions || Deploying pod only when the process inside other pod has finished

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Need some help on implementing better kubernetes resource deployment.

Essentially, we are trying to mention every resource in a single values.yaml file.
When you install the chart. All resources are created parallelly. Among these I've 2 components.
Let's say component1 and component2.

For component1, It's main function will be to install some dars into the server machine. This will take between 45 min to an hour.

For component2, It is dependent on some dars that will be installed onto server by commponent1.

Problem is, When you deploy helm chart and every pod is created at the same time.
Even though status for a pod for component2 will be running. When you inspect the container logs it will tell you process start up failed. Due to some missing classes(Which would've been installed by component1)

I am looking for a way, by which I can either introduce some delay until component1 is done or Keep destroying and recreating resources for component2 until component1 is done.

Delay based on if all dars are installed into server machine.

For restarting all resources for component2 I was thinking about creating a 3rd pod or a maintenance pod. Which will keep looking up both components1 and 2 , and it will keep restarting resource creation for component2 until component1 is done.

Readiness and liveliness probes will not work here because even though service startup has failed. Pod status will be running.

Any tips or suggestions on how to implement this will greatly help. Or if there's a better way to handle this.

Comment: If the second pod will just crash if the first pod isn't done yet, then you're set and you won't need to do anything.  Kubernetes will automatically restart it with a delay; it will be in CrashLoopBackOff state until it's ready to go.  (But if the first pod is compiling and installing software, doing this in your CI system and deploying a fully-baked image for the second pod would be a better setup.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the flag --wait or --wait-for-job according to your usecase as Helm will wait until a minimum expected number of Pods in the deployment are launched before marking the release as successful. Helm will wait as long as what is set with --timeout. Please refer the link [--wait flag detailed description](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#helpful-options-for-installupgraderollback)  and    https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/#options

`helm upgrade --install --wait --timeout 20 demo demo`

Comment: Yeah I tried with this. This will not work because the conditions in wait are based on pods or containers. But for our case even though the pods are up, the processes inside those pods are still under progress. If somehow I can change the setting to wait until you get the message.. "task completed" in logs, that should be able do something.